# Difference between [pointfree] and [tacit-programming]

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a significant difference between the [pointfree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointfree) and [tacit-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tacit-programming) tags? Should these be merged?

Comment: This might be a good question to ask on Programmers.SE to see if there actually is a difference, and then modify this question based on the results.

Answer (score 3):

## No, there's no difference. Yes, they should be merged.

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-free:

  > Point-free style in programming, called also tacit programming
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming:

  > Tacit programming, also called point-free style

It may take some work merging the tag wikis, though. And what should the combined tag be called?

Comment: How about tacit-programming, with pointfree as a synonym?